# Load text file into stringlist in Delphi XE-5 Firemonkey Android App

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I have a text file (tags.txt) that i would like to deploy with my app. I then want to load it into a TStringList at start up. As of now for testing purposes, i have it just in a button's onClick event. However, it doesn't seem to work. I have read a number of resources on line, including those from embarcadero and SO. I just do not know what i am doing wrong. I get a "Cannot open file "/data/data/com.embarcadero.PTMMobile/files/tags.txt".  No such file or directory.

Here is my code:

```
var
  frmMain: TfrmMain;
  AppPath: String;
  Tags: TStringList;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

uses System.IOUtils;

procedure TfrmMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Tags:= TStringList.Create;
  try
   AppPath := TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'tags.txt');
   Label1.Text:= AppPath;
   Tags.LoadFromFile(AppPath);
   Label2.Text:= IntToStr(Tags.Count);
  finally
   Tags.Free;
  end;
end;

end.
```

My remote path is **assets\internal**

[image]

Comment: I've had some buggy experiences with the deployment setup (as in I think it has bugs). Try removing the file, select All configurations - Android platform, then try adding it again.

Comment: Hmmm, i am little confused now. I just noticed that when i run the app (deploy it), the Tags.txt file gets removed from my PC. I was thinking that the txt file might get packaged up with the APK file. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Sentient  - that did not work.

Comment: Another interesting thing i should note is when I add my local file (tags.txt), the remote path becomes ".\", but all the literature I read showed "assets\internal". I tried both and neither worked.

Comment: So what result do you get if you put a label on your form, and set the caption to `TPath.GetDocumentsPath`? Doing so should show you where it thinks the file should be after your app is installed, right?

Comment: @KenWhite - I get the same result is is in the error above - /data/data/com.embarcadero.PTMMobile/files/tags.txt

Comment: Interestingly enough,  when the run dialog shows, i can see the deployment files cycle through on the run dialog, and i never see the tags.txt file, im thinking i should

Comment: OK. Continuing the troubleshooting you should be doing... So when you look at the file system on your mobile device, is the folder `/android/data/com.embarcadero.PTMMobile/files` present on your device? (On my Galaxy S3 running Ice Cream (Android 4.1.2), it would be beneath `storage/sdcard0/Adnroid/data/`, judging by the location of all my XE5 apps in the default locations.) If it isn't there, you're not deploying it properly. I can't see your device from here, so I can't tell yo where it's ending up.

Comment: Well, ill look, but i never see it deployed in the first place. Like I said, when the run dialog appears, and i see it iterating over the files being deployed, i never see my Tags.txt file shown. It is large, so it should show for at least a second or too.

Comment: the path i found it in was /android/data/com.embarcadero.PTMMobile/files/files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your screenshot it seems the original file is in the Debug binaries folder of your application. 
Try to move the file in the project folder and retry (of course you have to re-add the new file location to your deploy options).

The binaries folder may be cleaned up at each build, deleting your original file just before trying to deploy it to the device.

Hth

Comment: No that did not work. I removed the old instance of the file from the deploy manager and did a rebuild. I moved the tags.txt file to my project directory and then re-added it to the deploy manager. Once again, when the file is added, the remote path says ".\". I tried it with that path and got my original results and error. I then changed the remote path to "assets\files", and still get the exact same results and error

Comment: Sorry, Andrea, that did work. If I added the file to the projects folder and change the remote path from the default ".\"  to "assets\internal", it works!